# Entity Framework Code First Many to Many Relationship with Existing Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I have the following situation:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RecurringAppointment>()
    .HasMany(ra => ra.StaffMembers)
    .WithMany();
```

So a staff member (inherited from user) can have many recurring apointments and vice versa. Now, when I try to add staff members to recurringAppointment.StaffMembers like this ...

```
[Invoke]
public void ApplyStaffMembersToRecurringAppointment(int recurringAppointmentId, int[] staffMemberIds)
{
    var staffs = DbContext.Users
        .OfType<Staff>()
        .Where(s => staffMemberIds.Contains(s.Id))
        .ToList();

    var recurringAppointment = DbContext.RecurringAppointments
        .Include("StaffMembers")
        .Single(ra => ra.Id == recurringAppointmentId);

    foreach (var staff in staffs)
    {
        recurringAppointment.StaffMembers.Add(staff);
        DbContext.Users.Attach(staff);
    }

    DbContext.RecurringAppointments.Attach(recurringAppointment);
    DbContext.Entry(recurringAppointment).State = EntityState.Modified;
    DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

... it just won't save the changes. When I add values manually to the database it works perfectly, so the relation should be set up correctly.

I looked at tons of similar entries, but they all either didn't save or didn't attach. The code gets executed (I can debug). What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your Staff Object have a navigation collection referring back to your Recurring appointment?  When I had nav collections on both ReccuringAppointments and StaffMembers, the above code did not save changes.

If you only have the navigation collection on ReccuringAppointmets however it did work - unless I had set `AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false` in my configuration.

If neither of these cases happened, the code worked perfectly - if these cases aren't true for you, can you post your context/entities for more information?